# Regex to match 7numberdigits followed by ","

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching

I am trying to match (0 or more)occurrences of  7digit or more numbers followed  by "," Below is the regex i am using, but it doesnt help

^(\d{7,}(?:,\d{7,})*)$

Sample string - 122343,14435356,123254356,324556,121,45,124325,1343545,1323544
Output - 14435356,123254356,1343545,1323544

Comment: Remove `^` and `$`, use https://regex101.com/

Comment: Your output doesn’t match your regex - your regex matches the entire string using ^ and $ so the output should be ‘false’ as the input doesn’t match the regex. Please post your Java code as a [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your sample string doesn't have numbers at the start or end that are seven or more characters long. Simply removing the starting and ending constraints will return the matches you expect:

```
(\d{7,}(?:\,\d{7,})*)
```

Returns:

```
14435356,123254356
1343545,1323544
```

This can be seen on **[Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/ySIInZ/1/)**.

Answer (score 0):

**Regex**: `\b(?:\d{1,6},|,\d{1,6}$)\b|(\d{7,})` **Substitution**: `$1`

Output: `14435356,123254356,1343545,1323544`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/6Ngqym/2)

Java code:

```
String text = "122343,14435356,123254356,324556,121,45,124325,1343545,1323544";
text = text.replaceAll("\\b(?:\\d{1,6},|,\\d{1,6}$)\\b|(\\d{7,})", "$1");
System.out.print(text); //14435356,123254356,1343545,1323544
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative, simple, non-regex solution would be to just split the string by `,`, and loop through the results and check if greater than 6.

```
String[] split = s.split(",");
for (String string : split) {
    if (string.length() > 6) {
        System.out.println(string);
    }
}
```

Or if you like Java8 solutions, convert to a `List` and filter the stream:

```
List<String> myList = Arrays.asList(s.split(","));
myList.stream().filter(a -> a.length() > 6).collect(Collectors.toList()).forEach(System.out::println);
```